# AngularJS: Sum up values of child array inside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I was trying to display values of `AngularJS`. Now I want to sum up all the values to its parent variable sum.

**My AngularJs Array Looks Like:**

```
{  
   "isInternalInvoice":1,
   "name":"Invoices",
   "sum":50,
   "articles":[  
      {  
         "ID":"130.0000917-17.557000506.1",
         "betrag_netto":"20",
      },
      {  
         "ID":"130.0000917-17.557000581.1",
         "betrag_netto":"30"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in currentInternalInvoices" >

 <input type="text" ng-model="invoice.betrag_netto"  />

</tr>
```

**If I make changes in textbox it works:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.data.sum" ng-bind="$parent.data.sum"  />
```

But I want to sum up all the values while typing inside loop.

Comment: What do you mean by `while typing inside loop`?

Comment: @Mamun I think that loop is the `ngRepeat` directive

Comment: there are automatically created text boxes , depending upon array,

Comment: if i type one by one it should summ all values and save SUM to its parent variable

Comment: @SyedDaniyalAsif What about binding a function to each model (`ngChange`) that will trigger and calculate the sum upon change in the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a summing function

```
$scope.getSum = function() {
  return $scope.data.articles.reduce((a, b) => a+Number(b.betrag_netto), 0);
}
```

and something to output it

```
<div>{{getSum()}}</div>
```

and it will automatically update it's value whenever you change the value in the input boxes.

See this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/q4oxx6EVtV3NgthxmWge?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Change the html to add a ng-change event listener which sums withe new value as the input field is updated.

```
<tr ng-repeat="invoice in currentInternalInvoices" >

 <input type="text" ng-model="invoice.betrag_netto" ng-change="doSum()" />
</tr>
<input type="text" ng-model="data.sum"   />
```

Add this code in controller to handle the addition logic:

```
$scope.doSum = function() {
    $scope.data.sum = $scope.data.articles.reduce((a, b) => a+Number(b.betrag_netto), 0);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a custom directive

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  class MyController {
    constructor(dataService) {
      this.dataService = dataService;
      this.data = {
        sum: 0
      }
    }
    $onInit() {
      this.data = this.dataService.get();

      console.info('running');
    }

    static get $inject() {
      return ['dataService'];
    }

  }

  const app = angular.module('app', [])
    .factory({
      dataService
    })
    .controller({
      MyController
    })
    .directive({
      sum
    });


  function sum() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      bindToController: {
        sum: '=',
        sumSource: '=',
        sumBy: '@',
      },
      scope: true,
      controller: class {

        $doCheck() {
          this.sum = this.sumSource.reduce((sum, {
            [this.sumBy]: value
          }) => Number(sum) + Number(value), 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function dataService() {
    return {
      get() {
        return {
          "isInternalInvoice": 1,
          "name": "Invoices",
          "sum": 50,
          "articles": [{
              "ID": "130.0000917-17.557000506.1",
              "betrag_netto": "20",
            },
            {
              "ID": "130.0000917-17.557000581.1",
              "betrag_netto": "30"
            }
          ]
        };
      }
    };
  }

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController as c">
  <table sum="c.data.sum" sum-by="betrag_netto" sum-source="c.data.articles">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in c.data.articles">
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.betrag_netto">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
  {{c.data | json}}
  <div></div>
</div>
```